# What microdata should I use for a blog?

Tags: html, seo, blogs, microdata

The blog is basically a page that lists the summary of like 10 articles, each item title linking to the full article page.

I've seen:

- http://schema.org/Blog
- http://schema.org/Article (or maybe http://schema.org/BlogPosting ?)

Where do I use these?

Right now on the individual article page I have:

```
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">       

    <h1 itemprop="name"> <a href="..."> A title...  </a> </h1>    

    <div itemprop="articleBody">
       bla bla
    </div>

    ...

  </article>
```

Which is ok I guess, but what do I do on the article index page? Do I add these to each article and add `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog" itemprop="blogPosts"` to the container element of all articles? Because in the docs it doesn't appear that article is a child of blog...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I agree with what others say that the subject is very vague. Never the less I will attempt to express my thoughts on the matter and show you how I'm doing it on my blog.

I use both [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) and [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item types in the same document to mark up different things.

### Web page

I use [WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage) item type on the body tag (but you can also use any other parent of the breadcrumb). By doing so I can mark up my bread crumbs.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <ul itemprop="breadcrumb">
    <li>
      <a href="foo">foo</a> 
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="foo/bar">bar</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="foo/bar/baz">baz</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    
    ...
    
</body>
```

### Blog posts

When I loop the blog posts I use the [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item type on the wrapper that contains all of the blog articles. I mark every article with the property `blogPosts` and uses of course [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) as item type.

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
  <article itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    ...
  </article>
    
  <article itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    ...
  </article>
    
  ...
    
</section>
```

### Article page

***See edit below for an update to this opinion***

On the articles landing page I <s>don't</s> use the [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item type. But I do mark the post as a [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) item.

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  ...
</article>
```

---

<s>The only reason I can see that you would wanna mark something with a [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item type is because of the `blogPosts` properties and the fact to say that it is a blog. I think you fulfill saying that it's a blog by marking the article as a [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting).
I also don't think it's correct using the property in this context since this is used in a plural form. To me that reflect a different area of use.</s>

---

### Edit

I'm not sure if the schema has extended or if I missed it the first time around, but the [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item has a property called `blogPost` now, that is the singular form `blogPosts`. So then I would say that it makes more sense to mark up the main element as the [Blog](http://schema.org/Blog) item and use the `blogPost` property for the article and mark it up as a [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) item

Comment: Why on the loop articles you would use `itemprop="blogPosts"` insead than `itemprop="blogPost"` ?

Comment: @Pikk It's the plural form that should be used on a collection page. Better semantics..

Comment: It looks like that on https://schema.org/BlogPosting there is written that blogPost supersedes blogPosts - so from my understanding blogPost replaces blogPosts, and blogPosts is replaced by blogPost

Comment: My take on it; they explain an attribute that are used in a singular and plural form. However, if both are defined, the singular markups supersedes the plural markup. So both can't be marked up by https://schema.org/Blog

Comment: Markup is used by Google also https://firebase.googleblog.com/

Answer (score 7):

I would use http://schema.org/WebPage for your all up page since this allows you to define things like Breadcrumbs/navigation which are important for describing a site regardless of the particular content.

There is still a lot of work needed in the microdata schemas and you've pointed out what appears to be a gap -- there is no parent/child relationship between Article and anything else that I can see (e.g. 'Articleindex' or 'Articles').

I haven't really read anything that indicates this parent child hierarchy is super important anyways, unless the parent is experssing attributes which are important to convey, so I think you can get away with either.

However, you haven't mentioned what type of content the "articles" are. If they are more journalistic or official in nature (like a news article, research paper, etc) I'd use http://schema.org/Article for each article and not worry about the article index page. Otherwise, use http://schema.org/Blog http://schema.org/BlogPosting for each.

Answer (score 6):

The Article and Blog schema descriptions are pretty vague right now and will probably change sometime in the future, but i believe the Blog schema to be a little more relevant for a, well, blog (it's even implied in the Article schema description page down below, under "`More specific types`").

So, you can start by defining your main blog page with the higher level schema:

```
<!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
<meta itemprop="creator" content="Creator of the blog">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title of your Blog">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description of your blog">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.yourblog.com/main/image/pic.gif">
```

And you can define your blog pages with the second level blog schema, [BlogPosting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting), and define the appropriate item properties, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<meta itemprop="author" content="Author of your blog">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title of your content">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Description of your post">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.yourblog.com/post/image/pic.gif">
```

Urghh, complicated :P, there are a million properties you can employ, but just focus on the most important ones.

Answer (score 3):

Oops! this code is error!

```
<!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

You should use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

instead of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

When we declare the type of the blog, we can add it in body tag:

```
<body itemscope='' itemtype='http://schema.org/Blog'>
```

Inside of this section, we can use "Itemprop" as the property of the itemtype.
We're talking about the type of a site, not a basic language of a site.

Answer (score 2):

Here are other important **itemscopes** to use

- http://schema.org/ImageObject
- http://schema.org/Brand
- http://schema.org/Person

Example for `Person`

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
     <span itemprop="name">Mahdi Maghrooni</span>
     <img src="http://maghrooni.ir/img/users/FCwNdpWQKGQqiZphN6rj2YuHY3bXrF.jpg" itemprop="image" alt="Maghrooni" />
</div>
```