# Is there any schema.org type for teasers of a blog?

Tags: blogs, microdata, schema.org

Teasers on the front page of a blog surely are not the targets for us to add `itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting"` to because each of them is not a full blog posting and is just one or two paragraphs with a "Continue reading" link instead.

But since they are part of a blog, is there any blog-related Microdata for them or not?

Comment: Y may be this one help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866021/what-microdata-should-i-use-for-a-blog

Comment: @Prabu. Thanks. But it didn't provide an answer for teasers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [person](http://schema.org/Person) is still a person, even if you don’t provide the name. A [place](http://schema.org/Place) is still a place, even if you don’t provide the address. A [blog posting](http://schema.org/BlogPosting) is still a blog posting, even if you don’t provide the full content.

So using `BlogPosting` for a teaser is perfectly fine. If you don’t show the full content, just omit the [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) property.