# Blog Posts Optimized by Schema

Tags: metadata, microdata, schema.org, rich-snippets

I am quite new to these approach in optimizing my HTML with Rich Snippets. I am not sure what is the differences of each of the list items below:

1. http://schema.org/Article
2. http://schema.org/BlogPosting
3. http://schema.org/Blog

I got this code below example below, and I want to know what are the missing items or codes that could optimized a simple blog post that search engines can understand. I'd like to know all the rich snippets available for a blogpost.

---

```
<div id="blog_post" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <h2 itemprop="name headline">Post Title</h2>
            <div class="byline">
                Written by
                <span itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                    <span itemprop="name">
                        <a href="https://" itemprop="url" rel="author">Author</a>
                    </span>
                </span>
                on
                <time datetime="2011-05-17T22:00" itemprop="datePublished">Tuesday May 17th 2013</time>
            </div>
            <div class="content" itemprop="articleBody">Content...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`http://schema.org/Blog` can be used on the front page, where you typically find a list of several blog posts (and maybe also for blog-wide things on every page, like the blog name).

`http://schema.org/BlogPosting` represents a single blog post.

`http://schema.org/Article` is just [more general](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/46709/17633) than `http://schema.org/BlogPosting` (every `BlogPosting` is a `Article`, but not every `Article` is a `BlogPosting`). If you have a typical blog, you want to use `http://schema.org/BlogPosting`.

Comment: thanks for the concise explanation. Would mine sharing some of your codes, I am not sure how to do with the syntax especially the blog posting. Can I possible combine the three?

Comment: @lordzden: What’s wrong with your example? Simply look at all available properties at http://schema.org/BlogPosting and decide which you can use for your content. -- If you have a typical blog (only publishing blog posts), you don’t need `Article` at all.

Comment: I am using blogger, and I'd like to confirm that using the code, I have
   to put it on bloggers new post. right?

Comment: It's taken me days to find the answer to my question, by looking at the first sentence in your answer. There's no concise documentation that states how it should be for a blog index page. But another question would be, inside the Blog schema, would each blog excerpt actually be a blogPosting object there?

Comment: @Lee: Yes, each `BlogPosting` ([no matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20821707/1591669) it’s the full article or only a teaser) should be associated via `blogPost` to its `Blog`  ([similar to this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217262/1591669)).