# Which Schema.org property should I use for popular posts item list?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Example markup of what I have:

```html
<body  itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/WebPage'>
    <div id="main" itemprop='mainContentOfPage' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
        <article itemprop='blogPost' itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/BlogPosting'>
            blah blah blah
        </article>
    <div>
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li><article><img/>popular post article</article></li>
            <li><article><img/>popular post article</article></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</body>
```

What should I use for the articles within each list item? I thought of `articleSection`, but that doesn't make sense because it's not within an article schema. So I'm trying to wrap my around the best way to add Microdata here.

Moving the `aside` within the `article` isn't really a viable option either. This is Blogger, so doing that would be tricky, especially on the admin widget-management side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (2016)**: In the meantime Schema.org introduced a property to denote that an item is the main/primary one for a page: `mainEntity` ([see details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467088/1591669)). So the below answer is somewhat out of date.

---

If they are also blog posts, you would use [`BlogPosting`](http://schema.org/BlogPosting), too.

Microdata is not only for the main content of a page. However, the Schema.org vocabulary currently lacks a property to mark an item as the main content item of a page (the property [`mainContentOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage) is only allowed for `WebPage`).

By using [`articleBody`](http://schema.org/articleBody) for the main `BlogPosting`, capable consumers should be able to deduce that the other `BlogPosting` items on the page (which naturally don’t have the `articleBody` property) are only linked/related posts.

---

So it could look like:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">

  <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <div itemprop="articleBody">…</div>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
          <a href="/post-4" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Post 4</span></a>
        </article>
      </li>
      <li>
        <article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
          <a href="/post-5" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Post 5</span></a>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>

</div>
```

Comment: I am using webPage for the body element, and I added mainContentOfPage #main. Updated post to reflect my current markup.

Comment: So what your saying is that I should use articleBody instead of blogPost for the main article?

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks.

Comment: @Xarcell: Your updated example is not correct. You can’t use `mainContentOfPage` like that. I added an example to my answer how the `Blog` item could look like.