# Schema.org: Blog itemtype suitability

Tags: blogs, microdata, schema.org

I hope my question will not be too vague.

I am starting to dive into awesomness of microdata and Schema.org. What remains a little mystery to me is an exact specification of **itemtype BLOG** to me.

Does it work as a *general container for articles* of all kind or is it appropriate for *"regular" posts only*?

To clarify, here is my example: I am building my online webdesign portfolio. I have two `<sections>` - one for portfolio items, one for my regular blog (consisting from Twitter updates, videos and other microblogging formats). Should I mark both of them as "blogs", their content as "articles" or would you recommend me completely different approach.

I've found quite a lot of discussion about the role of `itemtype blog` but most of them concentrate at the usage of itemtypes in "regular blog situations".

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46680/using-schema-for-blogging-article-vs-blogposting
- [What microdata should I use for a blog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866021/what-microdata-should-i-use-for-a-blog)
- [Blog Posts Optimized by Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606021/blog-posts-optimized-by-schema)

Some commercial portfolio WP themes I was going through use "blog" itemtype for portfolio items, some don't bother mark the list at all.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

schema.org doesn’t define or explain the term *blog* (it only [says](http://schema.org/Blog): "A blog"). So in the end it’s up to you and your understanding of what constitutes a blog.

If your posts are `http://schema.org/BlogPosting`, you have a blog. If your posts are `http://schema.org/Article`, you don’t have a blog. Now the question is: When is a post a blog post?

A `http://schema.org/BlogPosting` is a more specific `http://schema.org/Article`. But they consist of absolutely the same properties, so again we have to base the decision on our understanding of the terms *article* and *blog posting*.

How to define *blog* or *blog post*? For me, content-wise, a blog is a (reverse chronological) collection of self-contained posts ([… and so on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blog)). But opinions may differ.

So I’d propose a simple rule of thumb:

Imagine a specialized blog search engine, making use of `http://schema.org/Blog` and `http://schema.org/BlogPosting`. Would it be useful for the searchers if your posts are indexed there? If not, don’t use these types.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with unor about difference between Blog, BlogPosting and Article. Just my two cents - to be a bit more specific at your particular case.

For blog *section* I'd use Blog and BlogPosting exactly as it written by Eric [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866021/what-microdata-should-i-use-for-a-blog).

I don't think that Blog should be used for portfolio items. Instead I'd use more specific types from schema.org (e.g., http://schema.org/ImageObject). They can be wrapped up in some "container" type like http://schema.org/ImageGallery or http://schema.org/ItemList.

Hope this helps.